# Get all tags name from XML (only the tags name)

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, parsing, tags

I am trying to print the all tags (only the tags name), and I have a problem with join:

```
DEXML = urlopen('# the URL of the XML')

tree_DE = ET.parse(DEXML)

root_DE = tree_DE.findall('.//*')
a = []

for element in list(set(root_DE)):
    x = str(element)
    m = re.search("'[a-zA-Z]+'", x)
    m = ",".join()
    a.append(m)

print(a)
```

After running this code the error is:
`TypeError: join() takes exactly one argument (0 given)`

Comment: It's impotent to me to print it in a list and without extra characters.
Example:
one of the results:
"<Element 'pubDate' at 0x00000000035DDEA8>"

I want just the: pubDate

Comment: Why regex? Why not `element.tag`?

Comment: Thank you Parfait, I did it with element.tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
DEXML = urlopen('# the URL of the XML')

tree_DE = ET.parse(DEXML)

root_DE = tree_DE.findall('.//*')
a = []

for element in list(set(root_DE)):
    x = str(element)
    seq = re.search("'[a-zA-Z]+'", x)
    # add seq argument 
    m = ",".join(seq)
    a.append(m)

print(a)
```

Comment: I can't download and install the seq:

DEPRECATION: --no-install, --no-download, --build, and --no-clean are deprecated.  See https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/906.
Downloading/unpacking seq
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement seq
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for seq
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\barak-s\pip\pip.log

Comment: seq is a variable, could be xy or baraks_variable.......join is missing argument means = join(missing argument here)......syntax: str.join(sequence)

Answer (score 0):

The right way:

```
PRD_XML = urlopen('URL.xml_1')
DEX_ML = urlopen('URL.xml_2')

for event, element in ET.iterparse(PRD_XML):
    PRD_tags.append(element.tag)

for event_2, element_2 in ET.iterparse(DEX_ML):
    DE_tags.append(element_2.tag)


def compare():
    if not [item for item in PRD_tags if item in DE_tags]:
        return False
    return True

assert_false(compare(), "no match")
```